# ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, create-table

**I 'm trying to make that table as a many to many relationship table and this error occur**

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
[SCREEN-SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40m2k.png)[SCREEN-SHOT 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7xys.png)

this is another test for my commands

```
CREATE TABLE `new_e`.`teach` (
  `instructor_i_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `course_c_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`instructor_i_id`, `course_c_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `i_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`i_id`)
    REFERENCES `new_e`.`instructor` (`i_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `c_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `new_e`.`course` ()
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Your c_id constraint, REFERENCES, you forgot something in the () at the end?

Comment: yes and i tried this too https://i.stack.imgur.com/40m2k.png

Comment: @M.Sherif, please don't use screenshots. Run SQL statements `SHOW CREATE TABLE instructor` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE course` and copy the **text.** Then edit your question above to paste these.

Answer (score 2):

The second foreign key definition:

```
FOREIGN KEY ()
REFERENCES `new_e`.`course` ()
```

requires one or more columns between the parentheses.

Comment: thanks for answering,
yeah i tried it but get the same problem

Comment: @M.Sherif . . . Bill is pretty good at this type of thing.  If you are still getting the same problem, you should edit your question and show the corrected code.  In the meantime, though, I would guess that the problem is the lack of references in the parentheses.

Comment: @M.Sherif You tried what? If you put one or more column names into the parentheses as suggested, you *can't* get the same problem.

Comment: @EJP telling me that i_id is not exist, but it is already exist https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7xys.png